# How to move the cursor to the last opened window (possibly popup) in c++

Tags: c++, winapi, mouse

I need to move the mouse to the last opened window. This last window will be a popup created by whatever website.
I guess all I need is to get the position of the last opened window and use SetMousePos, right?
I'm not really familiar with the windows API and any help is welcome - Thanks!

Edit:
To answer the questions, we are writing a program that gets malware data. Unfortunately some malware only start working after the mouse moves to a popup they opened. Its a research-based application

Comment: Why would you want this? but yes, setMousePos sounds like a good place to start

Comment: You're probably better off hosting a WebBrowser ActiveX control in a sandbox. As the hosting environment, you can control the popup.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this but I believe you could try the following:

1. Enumerate running processes and order by PID.
2. The highest number PID should be the "newest" process.
3. For the newest process enumerate its windows (use GetWindowThreadProcessId)
4. At this point I guess you'd have to pick which window you think is the "main" window, for example if the malware opens two windows I don't know how you're going to choose which one to give focus to?
5. Of your picked HWND get its position on the desktop.
6. Use SetMousePos to move the mouse to the position of the window.

I haven't included all the API's you'll need for these tasks as its generally quite easy to find on here :)

Answer (score 0):

One way to track recently opened windows is to use [SetWinEventHook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373640(v=vs.85).aspx) to listen to the EVENT_OBJECT_CREATE and EVENT_OBJECT_SHOW events. In the callback, filter:

- just events with a non-null HWND where idObject==OBJID_WINDOW to get just window creation events (vs other creation events such as for items within a listbox)
- for top-level only windows, also filter by checking [GetAncestor(hwnd, GA_PARENT)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633502(v=vs.85).aspx) is GetDesktopWindow()
- And check that the window is indeed currently visible (WS_VISIBLE style is set in GetWindowLong(GWL_STYLE)).

Also filter by GetWindowThreadProcessId() and via the thread/process you pass into SetWinEventHook if you only care about HWNDs from a specific app.

The reason for checking both of these events is that some windows are created hidden and then shown, others are created fully visible, while others are created once, then shown/hidden many times over their lifetime.

You can then cache this 'last known created hwnd' in a global and check it as needed, using GetWindowRect() to get its location, and SetCursorPos() to move the mouse to that location.

--

If the most recent popup is an active window which takes focus - as is the case with dialogs, but not usually the case with 'pop-under' windows - you can use [GetGUIThreadInfo(NULL, ...)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633506(v=vs.85).aspx) to determine the currently active HWND, which might be the one you are looking for, returned in the GUITHREADINFO.hwndActive member of the struct you pass it.